# Find array index on a 1d array from a 2d grid javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

Let's suppose I have the following grid and each cell of the grid has an index mapped to a 1d array.

```
0, 1, 2
3, 4, 5,
6, 7, 8
```

I could represent this with a 1d array like: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

I would like to know a simple way to map a 2d coordinate like `(3,1)` to its index in the array, in this case, would be `2`.

After researching a lot, I found a lot of people suggesting this equation: `index = x + (y * width)`, but it doesn't seem to work in my tests.

For example for `(1, 1)`, the result would be `index = 1 + (1 * 3) = 4`, and for `(3, 1)` would be `index = 3 + (1 * 3) = 6`, which does not make any sense to me.

Is it possible to achieve this in a simple way? Or I would need to use iterators like a for?

Comment: Do you know that index in js starts with 0?

Comment: 2D matrix notation is commonly `(row, col)`, with indexes starting at 0. Thus, `(3, 1)` is invalid (only 3 rows, from 0 to 2). If you start the index at 1, it would be `(3, 1) = 6`, 3rd row, 1rst column.

Comment: you should be using `index = x-1 + (y -1* width)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2D matrix notation is commonly `(row, col)`, with **indexes starting at 0**.

Thus, `(3, 1)` is invalid: only 3 rows, from 0 to 2. `(1, 1)` means 2nd row, 2nd colum, which is `4` in your example. The formula is thus:

```
(row * width) + col
(2, 1) = 2*3+1 = index 7
```

once again using 0 for the first row/col.

If you really want to keep thinking with indexes starting at one, just change the formula to:

```
((row - 1) * width) + (col - 1) = 1D index
```

Comment: I do want to note that, while I dislike it, math does often use 1-based indices.

Answer (score 3):

In your case it would be `index = (x - 1) + ((y - 1) * width)` as your coordinate system starts from 1 and arrays start from 0.

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

function getPosition(x, y, width) {
  return x - 1 + (y - 1) * width;
}

console.log({
  position: getPosition(3, 1, 3),
  element: arr[getPosition(3, 1, 3)]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed `index = x + y * width` (the parens are unnecessary) or `index = y + x * width`, depending on whether you want your flat array to keep the rows together as in your question (`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, `index = x + y * width`), or keep columns together (`[0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8]`, `index = y + x * width`). But indexes usually start at 0, not 1. So your (1, 1) would be (0, 0) and your (3, 1) would be (2, 0).

Here's the first:

```js
// 0, 1, 2
// 3, 4, 5
// 6, 7, 8
const a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let x = 0, y = 1;
let index = x + y * 3;
console.log(`(${x}, ${y}) is index ${index}, value ${a[index]}`);
x = 2;
y = 0;
index = x + y * 3;
console.log(`(${x}, ${y}) is index ${index}, value ${a[index]}`);
```

Here's the second:

```js
// 0, 1, 2
// 3, 4, 5
// 6, 7, 8
const a = [0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8];
let x = 0, y = 1;
let index = y + x * 3;
console.log(`(${x}, ${y}) is index ${index}, value ${a[index]}`);
x = 2;
y = 0;
index = y + x * 3;
console.log(`(${x}, ${y}) is index ${index}, value ${a[index]}`);
```